# What are these constructs in JS and YUI?

Tags: javascript, php, yui, yui2

I got the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110705/pass-data-from-server-side-to-yui-3-javascript-application), while searching for some way to access PHP variables from a YUI2 JavaScript function in a separate `.js` file.

Looking at the JavaScript, the first statement *creates the `namespace`*, the second statement *starts the definition of a function (named as YAHOO.MyApp)*. Then `var currencyRates;` and `var userInfo;` create two variables.

1. Then what is the next `return {...}` construct?
2. Then inside that, `function(newRates) { currencyRates = newRates; }`
       looks like a function (especially because PHP probably calls it and
       passes to it the array `$currency rates`? But overall what is
       `initCurrencyRates: function(newRates) { currencyRates = newRates;
       }`?

   What is `:` there (just like `=` is for assignment)?
3. Then what about the `();` in the end? What is
   the `something=function(){...}();` construct?

Can somebody explain the control flow? What is executed first and then what and then what?

**JavaScript:**

```
YAHOO.namespace('MyApp');

    YAHOO.MyApp = function() {

    var currencyRates;
    var userInfo;

    /*
    here a lot of code with event listeners and dom manipulations which uses currencyRates and userInfo variables
    */

    return {
        initCurrencyRates: function(newRates) { currencyRates = newRates; },
        initUserInfo: function(newUserInfo) { userInfo = newUserInfo; },
    }

}();
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$currencyRates = array('EUR' : 1.3245, 'GBP': 1.4322, 'RUB': 0.02334); //actually it comes from database
print '<script>YAHOO.MyApp.initCurrencyRates(' . json_encode($currencyRates) . ')</script>';

$userInfo = array('Name' => 'Jhon', 'ID' => 10); //actually it comes from database
print '<script>YAHOO.MyApp.initUserInfo(' . json_encode($userInfo) . ')</script>';

?>
```

Comment: The `{ foo: bar }` part is an **object literal**. Learn more about objects here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at Javascript object literals. They are a bit similar to PHP's hash literals. This Javascript code

```
var foo = {
    x: "hello",
    y: "world"
}
```

Is a bit similar to this PHP code:

```php
$foo = array(
    "x" => "Hello",
    "y" => "World"
)
```

Comment: The first one is JSON isn't it?

Comment: @Zarah: No, it's an object literal. JSON looks similar but is something very different. JSON is a textual, language-independent  data-exchange format, just like XML or CSV.

Comment: Felix King is saying that JSON is a format used to encode data inside a string. Its intentionally similar to the syntax for JS object literals though (the name stands for JavaScript Object Notation) but there are still some differences. For example, in JSON the keys must always be quoted and you cant have arbritrary expressions like `{ x : 1 + 1 }`

Comment: OK so `return {..}` is an object literal, and `initCurrencyRates` and `initUserInfo` are its properties (methods according to the link @FelixKling provided)? And what is the entire thingy with the parenthesis and `;` in the end, that is `something=function() {..}();`?

Comment: Thats a function expression that is being immediatelly invoked (IIFE). You should find a more in depth explanation if you search for "Javascript IIFE" and "Javascript module pattern"